# Can't load image from MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm creating a list of articles inside a section, but I'm having troubles getting the images out of my MySQL database. I followed this guide how to store images in MySQL http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914. This is the code I'm using.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM heroes");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<article>";
    if($row{'Type'} == 'Strength') {
        echo "<span class='strength'></span>";
    } elseif ($row{'Type'} == 'Agility') {
        echo "<span class='agility'></span>";
    } else {
        echo "<span class='intelligence'></span>";
    }
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<header>"."<h2>"."<a href='javascript:;'>".$row{'Name'}."</a>"."</h2>"."</header>";

    if($row{'Image'} != NULL) {
        ?>
        <img src="<?php base64_decode($row{'Image'}); ?>" alt="hero-image" width="200" height="300" />
        <?php
    } else {
        echo '<img src="images/no-image.png" alt="hero-image" width="200" height="300" />';
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</article>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using curly braces if you use `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: Replace `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysql_fetch_object`.

Answer (score 0):

replace your image source with

'data:image/gif;base64,'.base64_decode($row{'Image'});

also use proper mime instead of **gif**

Comment: it will only work if $row{'Image'}  consists of file string other wise use path based url

Comment: I can't get it to work, can you please edit my code so I can see exactly what you mend.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. You call mysql_fetch_array but then use curly braces which are meant for objects, yet you have an array.
2. You call base64_decode. This means that you will get binary content into your HTML which won't work. You have to encode it with `base64_encode` if it is stored in binary form.
3. The value of the `src` of a `<img>` must be a URL, not the content itself. In your case you can use a [Data-URL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-URL).

Comment: I can't get it to work. I even got the binary cod, encoded it and paste it manually and the image is still not displayed, and it is inside the MySQL.

Comment: @user2374907 Does your database contain the images in binary form or are the encoded in base64?

Comment: I have set the value of the image col to longblob, and when I click open value in editor there are 3 tabs "Binary,Text and Image"